# Using xml returned in curl function

Tags: php, xml, curl, ioerror

I have a curl function which connects to an API and returns xml.

I call this function from another script, and want to go through the xml and pick out some urls, but I get an I/O error so I think I am not handling the xml correctly.

This is the curl function

```
function &connect($url) {

    //If token is not set skip to else condition to request a new token 
    if(!empty($_SESSION['token'])) {


        //Initiate a new curl session
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        //Don't require header this time as curl_getinfo will tell us if we get HTTP 200 or 401
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
        //Provide Token in header
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '.$_SESSION['token']));
        //Execute the curl session
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        //Close the curl session
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;

    } else {

        //Run the getToken function above if we are not authenticated
        getToken($url);

        return 'error';

    }

}
```

This is it being called

```
//build url creates the api url required based on parameters passed into GET
$link = build_url;
//call the connect function and pass it the built link
$xml = connect($link);
//load the returned xml
$oxml = simplexml_load_file($xml);
```

The connect function is definitely getting the xml as I have echo'd it in the function and also when i run the script in my browser it outputs the xml to screen as well as "Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "1" in "

Im not sure what im missing :-(

Comment: is `build_url` a function? should it not be `build_url()` ?

Comment: `$oxml = simplexml_load_file($xml->asXML());` ... possibly?

Comment: nl-x yes, thats a typo i simplified it for posting above.

Comment: why is your connect function returning a reference? (and isn't it used as such when calling the function?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file();` loads XML from a file by passing it the file name.

Since you already have the XML string, you want `simplexml_load_string();` in stead.

**edit:**

Also you need to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` to tell curl to return the response, in stead of just returning a status code. The `1` that you are seeing is the status code.

Comment: I did try that but it throws up a different error, which is what makes me think something is wrong elsewhere or with the way im handling the xml. Even though if I call the API directly the xml returned is perfectly formed and valid.
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/join.php on line 50
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): 1 in /home/join.php on line 50
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/join.php on line 50

Comment: @PaulM I expected that much. Though you are a step closer now. The next question is why are you only getting '1' in stead of the XML ? I think you have a problem with your curl. (Though I still don't understand your function returning a reference, but not being used that way.) Check my edit.

Comment: Thats got it ;-) it was the missing returntransfer. Initially it was writing to a file but I wanted to use it so removed that line and didnt replace it.

I dont get references still so the above was a typo, I was playing with if it made a difference trying to educate myself!